# Sum up attribute value and text when option selected

Tags: jquery, magento

Many of the products on my friends website have different variants. Depending on the one you pick, the price is changing. The code for the price looks like this:

```
    <div id="WA_price">
        <p class="WA_price2">200&nbsp;€</p>
    </div>
```

When you choose a variant the code looks like this:

```
<dd class="last">
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="super_attribute[149]" id="attribute149" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
            <option value="">Option wählen…</option>
            <option value="28" price="139" data-label="1000 mm">1000 mm -10&nbsp;€</option>
            <option value="30" price="149" data-label="1200 mm" class="selected">1200 mm</option>
            <option value="32" price="159" data-label="1400 mm">1400 mm +10&nbsp;€</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</dd>
```

I found out that I have to add the value standing in the option-tag to the 200 €  standing in `<p class="WA_price2">200&nbsp;€</p>`.

What I cant figure out is how to get the price value and add it to the price standing in the p.WA_price2.

I suppose you first have to remove the `&nbps;€` and then get the number as a value, add it to the price-value and insert it again into the p-tag.

I only figured out how to remove the `&nbsp;€`

```
jQuery(".WA_price2").each(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/&nbsp;€/g, ''));
});
```

I really need some help and cant figure out. You can find my snippet [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a0n2qecb/).

Comment: Please create a working snippet. Those pieces of code does not help understanding what are you trying to do very much.

Comment: a working snipped cant be provided since I dont know where to start. Maybe I can explain in other words: If the option has the class "selected" the number standing in price="" should be added to the number standing in  <p class="WA_price2">200&nbsp;€</p>. In this case it would be 200 + xyz.

Comment: Ionut was asking for a working snippet, not necessarily a correctly working snippet. What he was really meaning was that he intends to see what you have exactly.

Comment: okay updated it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to get rid of `&nbsp;€`:

```
$this.html().replace(/&nbsp;€/g, '')
```

now you will need to parse this to a number and add it to the chosen value:

```
$this.html((parseInt($this.html().replace(/&nbsp;€/g, '')) + parseInt(jQuery("#attribute149").val())) + "&nbsp;€");
```

I assumed that you need to add the value of #attribute149 to the inner text's number. If I am wrong, then I kindly ask you to create a Fiddle with what you currently have and some scenarios a user could do with the expected result.

EDIT:

This is how the JS code should look like:

```
var priceContext = jQuery("#WA_price > .WA_price2")
var initialValue = parseInt(priceContext.html().replace(/&nbsp;€/g, ''));

jQuery("#attribute149").change(function() {
    priceContext.html(initialValue + parseInt(jQuery(this).find("option[value=" + jQuery(this).val() + "]").attr("price")) + "&nbsp;€");
});
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0n2qecb/1/).

Comment: You can see my snippet under [http://jsfiddle.net/a0n2qecb/](http://jsfiddle.net/a0n2qecb/)

Comment: Basically whenever someone is picking a different variant the price is changing and should be 200 + value of price in option-tag.

Comment: @Kazu thank you, will look into it and come up with an answer

Comment: @Kazu, please check out my edited answer, the solution to your problem is included now.

Comment: works perfectly AND most important I see what you did there. Thank you very much for your good and quick solution :)

Comment: @Kazu you are welcome, I wish you good luck with your project.